# Solving a simple exponential equation

Tags: calculus, logarithms

How can I solve this logarithm:

> $$ e^{2x} - 3 e^x + 2 = 0. $$

I think it should be re-written as a quadratic equation in $e^x$.

Comment: yes you can do it by rewriting this eqn as quadratic eqn

Comment: Just put $y = x^2$ and proceed to solve a quadratic equation in $y$. After you get the values for $y$, solve for $x$.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how, I'm having one of those days..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$e^{2x}-3e^x+2=0$$
let $e^x=y$
$$y^{2}-3y+2=0$$
$$y^2-2y-y+2=0$$
$$y(y-2)-1(y-2)=0$$
$$(y-2)(y-1)=0$$
$$(y-2)=0\;,(y-1)=0$$
$$y=2,1$$
$$e^x=2\;\;,\;\;e^x=1$$
$$\log_ee^x=\log_e2\;\;,\;\;\log_ee^x=\log_e1$$
$$x=\log_e2,x=0$$

Checking the answer:
$$e^{2x}-3e^x+2=0$$
$x=\log_e2$ put this value in eqn.
$$e^{2\log_e2}-3e^{\log_e2}+2=0\implies e^{\log_e2^{\large 2}}-3e^{\log_e2}+2=0\implies4-6+2=0\;\;satisfy$$

$x=0$ put this value in eqn.

$$e^{\large 0}-3e^{\large 0}+2=0\implies 1-3+2=0\;\;satisfy$$

so both answer are correct.

Comment: Isn't there only one correct answer though?

Comment: @jaykirby both answers are correct just  put these value of x in equation they satisfy it

Comment: my paper says there is only one correct answer

Comment: @jaykirby Okay I've edited my answer

Answer (score 5):

You can also factor the expression directly as $(e^x-1)(e^x-2)$.

Comment: This is so much easier than the other solutions. Rather straight forward.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how you would proceed to factor it please?

Comment: @jaykirby You have to "see it" as you might see a quadratic equation: First, determine that $e^{2x}=e^x\times e^x$.  You will thus have $(e^x\pm \_\_\_)(e^x\pm\_\_\_)$. Then, look at the coefficient of the last term, and find its factors (in this case, 2 and 1, or -2 and -1).  Then see if those factors add to the coefficient of the middle term (-2 and -1 add to -3).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let

$$y=e^x \implies e^{2x}=y^2 ,$$

and subs back in the equation and solve for $y$.

Comment: +1 Nice hint. Is that subs the same as substitution?

Comment: @BabakS.: Yes, subs stands for substitute. Thanks for the comment.